# How to hook Log Analytics / Azure Monitor into role assignments?

Tags: azure, roles, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring

Is there a way to hook Log Analytics or Azure Monitor into Role Assignments in order to capture when a new user/service principal/group is added to a Role for any resource within a tenant?

I'm looking for a log to tie alerts to. Something with a human readable `DisplayName` for both the user/sp/group and the resource its applied to.

**Example:**

- `Bob Smith` was assigned `Contributor` role to Storage Account `stg123` in Resource Group `rgabc`

Comment: Did you try `Get-AzLog -StartTime (Get-Date).AddDays(-7) | Where-Object {$_.Authorization.Action -like 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/*'}`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-accs-escontrol/change-history-report

Comment: Helpful link, thank you (though there is a typo in your link and it 404's) I was able to change the URL and find your intent. Specifically [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/change-history-report#azure-monitor-logs)

Comment: @ericOnline pls allow me to sum up your discussion below so that it may help others when they have similar requirement :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What @Satya provided, azure portal has `activity logs` and it is the most easy way to query role assignments in azure, and as @ericOnline said above, azure monitor also provides similar feature.

See details in : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/change-history-report

[image]

[image]